# String manipulation in C#. Inserting "+" between words

Tags: c#, string

This is as far as I have got. My thinking was to stuff the string into an array, format it and recast it into a string.

```
    //input search term
    Console.WriteLine("What is your search query?:");
    string searchTerm = Console.ReadLine();

    //stuff the search term into an array to split it out
    string separator = " "; //assumes search terms are separated by spaces
    string[] searchTermArray = searchTerm.Split(separator.ToCharArray());

    //construct the search term
    string searchTermFormat = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < searchTermArray.Length; i++)
    {
        searchTermFormat += searchTermArray[i] + "+";
        //Console.WriteLine(searchTermFormat);
    }
```

Desired output

```
word1+word2+word3
```

where the number of words are not fixed.

Comment: Clarify: what does your input look like? Is it just a string like `word1 word2 word3`, an array, ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You're looking for `String.Join("+", searchTermArray)`
- You're trying to write `searchTerm.Replace(' ', '+')`
- You probably should be writing [`Uri.EscapeDataString(searchTerm)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.Join` to concatenate the strings together.

Answer (score 0):

Try `string.Replace(" ", "+")`

Answer (score 0):

That a typical String.Replace job or RegEx

Answer (score 0):

What about myString.Replace(' ', '+');